# Java - Endless while loop with FadeIn & FadeOut animation

Tags: java, android, while-loop, fadein, fadeout

I have an requirement to show the text on Recyclerview with FadeIn & FadeOut animation.

Below is the dynamic list where it's need to loop infinite items i.e; 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3

```
List<String> mImageDesc = new List<String>();
mImageDesc.add("1");
mImageDesc.add("2");
mImageDesc.add("3");
```

I have used below code but which is not working for me.

```
final  Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in_animation);
        final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_out_animation);

        Animation.AnimationListener animListener = new Animation.AnimationListener(){

            // Required to change the image
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                if (animation == animationFadeIn) {
                    // Start fade-out animation
                    mTxtImageDescription.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
                } else if (animation == animationFadeOut) {
                    *while(mImageDesc.listIterator().hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(mImageDesc.listIterator().next());
                        mTxtImageDescription.setText(mImageDesc.listIterator().next());
                        mTxtImageDescription.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);*
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Set listener to animation
        animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(animListener);
        animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(animListener);

        // Start fade-in animation
        mTxtImageDescription.setText(mImageDesc.get(0));
        mTxtImageDescription.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
```

Comment: Just by printing `mImageDesc.listIterator().next()` you are "consuming it" and the next line call to `mImageDesc.listIterator().next()` is already on the next item

Answer (score 0):

In the last line off your while loop you have RE-started the 'animationFadeIn' ,so
the 'animListener' callbacks will be called forever .Notice if while loop was that repeating you would have 'StackOverflowError'.

Comment: @Omod Nejabbasi, What would be solution for this?

Comment: You can use two different  `AnimationListener` for each animation.